# AVL tree - manual drawing and printing

Tags: graphics, binary-tree, avl-tree

Is there any program/app that draws and save avl tree charts ? To pdf format preferably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you see  [AVL tree Applet](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~stan/csi2514/applets/avl/BT.html)

it is a ready tree. you can insert as many as you want then  print page or save as PDF.

Best regard.